# In Premiere Pro, how do I set the fps of a video to publish?

Tags: premiere

In Premiere Pro, how do I set the fps of a video to publish?

For example, I have imported an audio of 200MB

I've added an image.

And when I export, it says the estimated file size is 13GB.

Really the file size should not be more than 500MB.  A video frame rate of 3fps is fine for me.

But I can't see any setting to change the frames per second for the video that is published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select minimum bitrate for video, especially if your video have only 1 image.
If you will look how h264 codec works, you will know that it creates one "basic frame" each 'n' frames and then it creates "intermediate frames" only with areas of pixels which were changed.

I have tried some variants and can show you how fps affect on file size. And how keyframe distance affect to file size.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZobMxAzPQi2NaVfLDa5wYrHN87tIc11h

You can look at these 5 files.

[image]

Sample_minimum video BitRate_10 fps_keyframe distance = 300 - audio bitrate 320kbps.mp4 has size - 1 348 883

Sample_minimum video BitRate_10 fps_keyframedistance - standart - audio bitrate 320kbps.mp4 has size - 1 943 816

Sample_minimum video BitRate_30 fps - audio bitrate 320kbps.mp4 has size - 1 983 552

Sample_minimum video BitRate_30 fps_keyframe distance = 300 - audio bitrate 320kbps.mp4 has size - 1 544 303

Sample_without video - audio bitrate 320kbps.mp4 has size - 1 210 771 B

Minimum bitrate you can set here:

[image: Minimum bitrate you can set here]

Comment: Also in this post you can read another solve of similar problem.
https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23061/adobe-premiere-video-size-with-static-image?rq=1

Comment: thanks,  pushing that "target bit rate" down to the far left (which seems to be the option you are saying to change), has made it much smaller. Your animation does show you doing other things like flicking to the audio tab scrollup up and down doing nothnig there, also the video tab I notice you have frame rate of 10 . When I change mine from the default of 25 to 10, it doesn't change "estimated file size". . The key frame distance, mine is 90, if I change it to  300 it seems to make no difference to estimated file size

Comment: Hi Barlop!
In my test changing framerate from 25 to 10 fps has changed size of output file, but insignificant.
Keyframe distance affects on file size slightly, but it also depends on many factors and one of them it dynamic of changing frames in video.
If you need to do the most small size of file each from these parameters will be useful for you.

I have showed all settings of rendering which I changed. In audio tab you can also change bitrate to lower if you need to have file with lower size. Experimentally you can find balance of quality and size.